# How to combine TextView on ImageView?

Tags: android, textview

in my app i am using textview and imageview . i want combine the textview on imageview at the time of saving the image view.
please help me.

Comment: Use `RelativeLayout` and add an `ImageView` and a `TextView`

Comment: is it possible to drag the text in image view, see my xml code on top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i achieved by using this :

```
Bitmap mBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(originalBitmap,bw,bh,true);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
tv.draw(canvas);
mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will help you  [Merge Textview and ImageView](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html)

Comment: that is static, in my app. i have dynamical change's of ImageView and TextView

Comment: i cant understand what you are asking about. what dynamically change, is that your layout view or text content.??

Comment: How can you change your textview and imageview dynamically, you cant do that. where you are getting the text content and image.??

Comment: where you are getting Text and image dynamically..??

Comment: In your source file you mentioned only one image from Raw folder "R.drawable.girl". how it dynamically change..?? i think your logic is wrong.

Comment: sorry, only one image only text changes.

Comment: then its simple, put your text string globally and whenever button clicks, change the content of the string it automatically change your textview content dynamically.

Comment: textview changes properly that's ok, when save the originalBitmap i want that text also combine with image. this is code for image save:http://dl.dropbox.com/u/38493970/Full.java that means merge text with image.

Comment: you can never do like this. if you want to save both text and image i have a idea, create separate folder for each image and text. Save image and text inside the folder and maintain till it continuous. we cant do like photoshop editing.

Comment: i am not talking about editing the image, merging the text with image, if u want check my full code.

Comment: what do you mean, both are same. editing image or merging image are same.

Comment: it's possible like (combining two bitmaps one overlay another at the time of saving).

Comment: better option is save all your text in xml file and images in separate folder. parse the image and text using xmlparser if you need. you cant merge text with image.  we are not here to give logical ideas to your issue.

Comment: Error 404 - File not found. Could you update the link please ?